# I’m 24 years old with a baby voice

Tags: voice-training, voice-change

I want to change my voice how do I do that because my voice sound like a little kid voice

Comment: A voice teacher, speech pathologist, or other professional could help you with this in ways the internet cannot.

Comment: More details please. Is your voice very high pitched and you want to make it lower pitched? Is your articulation blurry like with a baby with no teeth? We can't answer if we have to guess.